# Shiny: validate for a group of checkboxGroupinput

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have a small shiny application that will take a user's input and create a plot based on it later on.
So far my sidebar looks like this: [image: like this]

I now would like to use "validate" to check if one of the 6 options of colors is clicked and if not, ask the user to to so.

So far my code checks only for the color red.

I am also wondering if there is way to have one box (for fruit for example)
automatically checked the whole time. For example: starting the app Apple is preselected, but if you unclick it, Banana (or Citrus) automatically get choosen. Is there a solution using this approach instead of validate?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Upload",
           sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                           '.csv')),
                        #tags$hr(),
                        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                     c(Comma=',',
                                       Semicolon=';',
                                       Tab='\t'),
                                     ',')
           ),
           mainPanel(dataTableOutput('table1')
           ))
  ),
  tabPanel("fruits",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                          uiOutput("fruitTable")
                          ),
           mainPanel(dataTableOutput('table2')
    )))
)))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  file_data <- reactive({
    fruit_file1 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(fruit_file1)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      fruits <- fread(fruit_file1$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, check.names = FALSE)
      return(fruits)
    }
  })
  

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(file_data())){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      datatable( file_data(),options = list(pageLength = 25))
    }
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(file_data())){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      
      validate(
        need(input$fruit, 'Check at least one fruit!'),
        need(input$stim, 'Check at least one fertilizer!'),
        need(input$marker1, 'Check at least one color!')
      
     
      datatable( file_data(),options = list(pageLength = 25))
    }
  })
  
  output$fruitTable <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(file_data())){
      return()
    }else{
      tagList(
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "fruit",
                           label = "Fruit",
                           choices = c("Apple", "Banana", "Citrus")),
        radioButtons(inputId = "month",
                     label = "Month",
                     choices = c("1"= 1, "9" = 2, "12" = 3 ),
                     selected = 1,
                     inline = TRUE),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "stim",
                           label = "Stimulation",
                           choices = list("A","B", "C")),
                           #choices = c(unique(as.character(file_data()[,3])))),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "marker1",
                           label = "red",
                           choices= list("+", "-"),
                           #choices = c(unique(as.character(file_data()[,4]))),
                           inline = TRUE),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "marker2",
                           label = "green",
                           choices= list("+", "-"),
                           #choices = c(unique(as.character(file_data()[,5]))),
                           inline = TRUE),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "marker3",
                           label = "yellow",
                           choices= list("+", "-"),
                           #choices = c(unique(as.character(file_data()[,6]))),
                           inline = TRUE)
      )
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and a link to the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9dfegwM-RmfZ3NYZ0FSS0dRQWc) I used.

After uploading the file you need to switch tabs to fruit.(I have not figured out yet, how to automatically have the tab switched after uploading)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
need(!is.null(input$marker1) | !is.null(input$marker2) | !is.null(input$marker3), 
  'Check at least one color!')
```

Comment: I updated my post with your solution and would like to know how to filter the colors as a group. If the input is not null, then select the rows of the table that are selected.                                                                                           
`if (!is.null(input$marker1) | !is.null(input$marker2) | !is.null(input$marker3)){
# ????    datatable(file_data()[file_data()?? %in% ??,options = list(pageLength = 15))` it's working for fruit and fertilizer , but I cannot get it done for the whole color group. Thanks!

Comment: hey, i think you should post a new question for that as it is not too related to the first question. You can refer me to the new question then and i can help,..

Comment: I figured it out myself.